# SSRS rendering to pdf always shows date as MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence

When I run the report to the report viewer , the dates come back correctly in the format DD/MM/YYYY using the render method provided by the report viewer. When I save the report and set format to PDF, the date will be as MM/DD/YYYY.

Why the date appears different on Viewer and PDF?
How can I make it as DD/MM/YYYY on both viewer and PDF, knowing that I used Format(Fields!YourDateField.Value,"DD/MM/YYYY") but I get the same issue?

Comment: Have you set the report > localisation language correctly?
You check by adding a textbox with the value, "=User!Language"

Comment: The User!Language is **fr-FR**

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue, but converting the date to a string (replace with your field) might be the key, especially with regard to exporting to PDF.

`=CDate(Globals!ExecutionTime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`